# Select doesn´t shown string value, only integer

Tags: php, laravel

**I´ve got 2 questions.**

***First question***

I am using a form to create an exam reservation. My problem is when I create my variables and send to the view, I can only select several values by their `id`. It seems it doesn't change from `integer` to `string`.

For example, if it appears "1" I would like to show "C1 Advanced English".

**Form.blade.php**

```html
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('exam_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="exam_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">Exam</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="exam_id" name="exam_id">
             <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('exam_id', optional($exams)->level ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select exam</option>
         @foreach ($exams as $key => $exam)
       <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('exam_id', optional($exams)->level) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $exam }}
       </option>
   @endforeach
        </select>

        {!! $errors->first('', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="user_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">User</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="user_id" name="user_id">
             <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('user_id', optional($users)->name ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select user</option>
         @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
       <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('user_id', optional($users)->name) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $user }}
       </option>
   @endforeach
        </select>

        {!! $errors->first('user_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('booking_date') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="booking_date" class="col-md-2 control-label">Booking Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="booking_date" name="booking_date">
             <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('booking_date', optional($dateExams)->date ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select booking date</option>
         @foreach ($dateExams as $key => $dateExam)
       <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('booking_date', optional($dateExams)->date) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $dateExam}}
       </option>
   @endforeach
        </select>

        {!! $errors->first('booking_date', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

**ExamreservationController**

```php
    class ExamReservationsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the exam reservations.
     *
     * @return Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $examReservations = Exam_reservation::with('exam','user','date_exam')->paginate(25);

        return view('exam_reservations.index', compact('examReservations'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new exam reservation.
     *
     * @return Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $exams = Exam::pluck('id','level')->all();
        $users = User::pluck('name','id')->all();
        $dateExams = Date_Exam::pluck('exam_id','date')->all();

        return view('exam_reservations.create', compact('exams','users','dateExams'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a new exam reservation in the storage.
     *
     * @param Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse | Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {

            $data = $this->getData($request);

            Exam_reservation::create($data);

            return redirect()->route('exam_reservations.index')
                ->with('success_message', 'Exam Reservation was successfully added.');
        } catch (Exception $exception) {

            return back()->withInput()
                ->withErrors(['unexpected_error' => 'Unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request.']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified exam reservation.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $examReservation = Exam_reservation::with('exam','user')->findOrFail($id);

        return view('exam_reservations.show', compact('examReservation'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified exam reservation.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $examReservation = Exam_reservation::findOrFail($id);
        $exams = Exam::pluck('id','id')->all();
        $users = User::pluck('name','id')->all();

        return view('exam_reservations.edit', compact('examReservation','exams','users'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified exam reservation in the storage.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @param Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse | Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        try {

            $data = $this->getData($request);

            $examReservation = Exam_reservation::findOrFail($id);
            $examReservation->update($data);

            return redirect()->route('exam_reservations.index')
                ->with('success_message', 'Exam Reservation was successfully updated.');
        } catch (Exception $exception) {

            return back()->withInput()
                ->withErrors(['unexpected_error' => 'Unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request.']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified exam reservation from the storage.
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse | Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        try {
            $examReservation = Exam_reservation::findOrFail($id);
            $examReservation->delete();

            return redirect()->route('exam_reservations.index')
                ->with('success_message', 'Exam Reservation was successfully deleted.');
        } catch (Exception $exception) {

            return back()->withInput()
                ->withErrors(['unexpected_error' => 'Unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request.']);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get the request's data from the request.
     *
     * @param Illuminate\Http\Request\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getData(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'exam_id' => 'string|required',
            'user_id' => 'string|required',
            'booking_date' => 'date|after:tomorrow|required',
            'status' => 'string|min:1|nullable',
        ];


        $data = $request->validate($rules);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

**ExamReservation Model**

```php
    class Exam_Reservation extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'exam_reservations';

    /**
    * The database primary key value.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
                  'exam_id',
                  'user_id',
                  'booking_date',
                  'status'
              ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [];


    public function setBookingDateAttribute($value):void
    {
        $this->attributes['booking_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    public function getBookingDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->format(config('app.date_format'));
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the course for this model.
     *
     * @return App\Models\Course
     */
    public function exam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Exam::class);
    }

    public function date_exam()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Date_Exam::class, Exam::class);
    }


}
```

***Second question***

The third input is a dynamic select. I would like to know if it´s possible only displays the dates that belong to an specific exam.

The select works with an dates. Does anyone know how to threat dates in a select?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

**First question**

You are outputting `{{ $exam }}` `{{ $user }}` and `{{ $dateExam }}` within the `<option>` tags. You might want to specify which attribute of the models you want to show, for example `{{ $user->email }}`.

**Second question**

Solution 1: You could combine the exam and dates dropdowns so the user has to select both at once.

```
<option>Exam A on date 1</option>
<option>Exam A on date 2</option>
<option>Exam B on date 3</option>
```

Solution 2: Split the form over multiple pages. In form 1 an exam is selected, in  page 2 the date.

Solution 3: Load the dates after an exam has been selected by using Javascript and an AJAX request.